# What is the good practice to dynamically add/remove nested attributes in the form in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have three models, Paper, Author, and Authorship. A paper can have several papers, which are recorded through Authorship. To be specific:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorships
    has_many :papers, :through => :authorships
end
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorships, inverse_of: :paper, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :authors, :through => :authorships
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :authorships, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Authorship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :paper
    belongs_to :author
    validate: rank, presence: true  # position of the author
end
```

Now I want to create/edit a paper. When the form pops out, I hope to dynamically enter any number of authors. The following is an illustration what I want to achieve:

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, we just use the `author_id` in the example. What is a good way to implement `_form.html.erb` in Paper view? I use nested form in the current implementation, and use javascript to add/remove `input` tags in html. Right now I don't have any problem to add a new paper, but when I visit edit action and try to remove authors, they are never removed. What is a good practice to achieve my goal?

**P.S.**

For the remove-the-last-author button, I've tried different combinations to manipulate the `input` tags in html, including totally removing any `input` related to one author (authorship_id, author_id, ...) and adding an `input` which set `_destroy` as true, all are no luck. Was also wondering how RoR knows when activerecords need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the 'delete last author' and add a remove button for each row.

[image]

Then add a JQuery handler on each delete button. Give the delete buttons a `data-id` attribute so you can fetch the row id easily. `$('.delete').click(function () { $(this).data('id')`

Add a `#destroy` method on the PapersController that handles AJAX requests and responds with JSON.  Delete the author in that method. `@author.destroy`

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html for more.

Here is an alternate way, without AJAX: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#removing-objects

Comment: I probably will go for the alternative way you suggested because it close to what I have right now. Just one question: In the sec. 9.6 of the last link, it states: "Rather than rendering multiple sets of fields ahead of time you may wish to add them only when a user clicks on an 'Add new address' button. Rails does not provide any built-in support for this. When generating new sets of fields you must ensure `the key` of the associated array is unique - the current JavaScript date (milliseconds after the epoch) is a common choice." What does the key refer to?

Comment: It refers to the array index of the post parameters when you send the results back to the server. When you use 'Add New' button, either an AJAX call will return an empty row of HTML to insert (may also actually create the row in the DB and return the id), or JavaScript will insert an empty row to fill in. Look at the last code block in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms